# How can i make 2 partitions on my USB Stick and put ISOs in them?

Tags: partitioning, bios, iso-image

Can i make 2 partitions and put 2 ISOs on them so when i boot into BIOS it says something like USB(1) for first partition and USB(2) for second?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When booting into BIOS, it will only recognise the USB as 1 device, no matter how many partitions you create.

However, you can possibly create a GRUB-like OS loader on the USB. Then, when you boot onto the USB, from there you can select the OS.

The tutorial below shows how to make dual-boot USB:

http://www.makeuseof.com/tag/how-to-install-multiple-bootable-operating-systems-on-one-usb-stick/

Comment: Interestingly, I was just searching for how to "chainload" from grub into syslinux/isolinux (that's used on many live iso's) and apparently grub just can't do that. grub4dos might be able to... Makes it a little harder to have a multiboot usb with any different live linux iso, the syslinux menus are often very different from a plain grub entry